# TypeORM - Cannot read property 'retryAttempts' of undefined on Docker

Tags: node.js, typescript, docker, typeorm

I've had a problem with starting nestJS app in docker container, after run `nest start` i've got this error, and I have no idea what to fix this:

```
worker | [31m[Nest] 29   - [39m07/07/2022, 5:25:37 PM   [38;5;3m[ExceptionHandler] [39m[31mCannot read property 'retryAttempts' of undefined[39m[38;5;3m +11ms[39m
worker | TypeError: Cannot read property 'retryAttempts' of undefined
worker |     at Function.<anonymous> (/dist/node_modules/@nestjs/typeorm/dist/typeorm-core.module.js:195:63)
```

can someone help me with this error?

package.json

```
"@nestjs/typeorm": "^8.1.4",
"typeorm": "^0.3.6",

  "engines": {
    "node": "16.11.1"
  }
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:16.3.0-alpine as builder

WORKDIR /dist

COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install --force

COPY . .
RUN  npm run build

EXPOSE 8080

CMD [ "npm", "run", "dev"]
```

locally i can't reproduce this error